HP ZBook 15 G5 + Thundebolt 3 power delivery?
I get a HP ZBook 15 G5 (3AX06AV) with its latest BIOS version running Ubuntu 22.04.4 and a HP Thunderbolt 3 dock (aka TB3).
I've checked in the BIOS settings for TB ports and everything looks fine.
So far, I've been able to connect an external VGA screen with success, I did not try other functionalities so far such as USB drive or audio device.
I'd expect that when powering the TB3 with a 230W HP power supply, the ZBook would be powered too, but it's not the case.
From what I can read here it think it should be working.
I've tried with 90W and 150W power supplies without success.
Anyone gets an idea what I should do to make it work, if possible?

The notebook controls this itself, not the OS. If the notebook is not charging from the dock, you may want to check the rated wattage of the cable you’re using. They’re not all rated the same, and most will max out at 15W unless you’ve bought quality cables with a stated rating from a trusted vendor.

Thanks @matigo
By cable, I guess you mean the 'Thunderbolt/AC power cable' I got with the TB3?
BTW, this TB3 HP reference is HSTNN-CX01.
Now, how could I check how much W the cable is out?

Could it be that I'd need a combo cable, that is a cable with, both end, an usb-c connector for the data AND a round connector for the power, like the one that can be seen here
